# AppleScript: 'Which <command>’ exited with non zero status

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I know that when invoking shell command with `do shell script` it doesn’t search for all the locations, so I should use full path to command. Therefore, what I’m doing is that `set cmmd to (do shell script “which <command>”)`, and then `do shell script cmmd…`. However, the former line gives an error: *The command exited with non-zero status*. I don’t understand why this is happening, when the same command in terminal exits fine.

What would be  work around for this? Also is there a better way that I should be using.

Comment: is the command that is not being found a built in one, if so what is the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `which` command uses the shell environment variable `$PATH` to search in different directories. Similar commands like `whereis` will uses sysctl and look for the property `user.cs_path`. The difference is that the `whereis` will give the same output no matter in which environment you're currently in. `which` can return different results if the variable `$PATH` is different between shells.

The difference between Terminal and a `do shell script` command is that they use both different shells. Terminal is probably using bash on your machine and `do shell script` is using sh, which is actually bash but running in another mode. When using `echo $PATH` shell command both in Terminal and using a `do shell script` you will get different results. That explains why the path is missing in your `do shell script` command. Probably using `whereis` would give no results in both do shell script and Terminal because the number of directory it searched is smaller.

To me the easiest way of solving this if anyone want the same output as in the Terminal is just invoking the same shell as the Terminal does and not try to copy variables from them. The command you probably want to use is:

```
do shell script "bash -l -c 'which <command>'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I surmise that the commands works in your Terminal window because you have added the path to `.bashrc` or whatever.
A quick fix is to `echo $PATH` in the Terminal windo, copy the result to the clipboard, and then prepend your do shell script command with `export PATH=<your paths> ;`. (Your really *must* end it with a semicolon.) Now you can use the which command, to find your stuff, I recommend using `which -a`, so you get a list of all occurences of your utilities.